# Misplaced Div Tag Causing Issue Displaying HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div tag which seems to be in the wrong place. When I run the code it appears as what appears to be a broken image link in a browser - and a highlighted yellow  tag in Dreamweaver.

The problem is when I try to move it - or remove it - it throws off the formatting of my page completely and I'm not sure exactly what I've done wrong in this instance. I've tried adding an extra div tag (thinking maybe I forgot one) but that does not seem to be the issue.

### Screenshot:

[image]

### JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/rMk5a/

### HTML Source Snippet:

```
<!-- sidebar -->
<aside id="sidebar" role="complementary">
</div>
<br />
<br />
<br />



<div id="text-18" class="widget widget_text">           <div class="textwidget"><a class="button blue " href="docs/BWL-T8-10-IXX-3000.pdf" >Model BWL-T8-10-IXX-3000</a>
<a class="button blue " href="docs/bwl-t8-10-ixx-3500.pdf" >Model BWL-T8-10-IXX-3500</a>
<a class="button blue " href="docs/bwl-t8-10-ixx-5000.pdf" >Model BWL-T8-10-IXX-5000</a>

<a class="button blue " href="docs/bwl-t8-18-ixx-3000.pdf" >Model BWL-T8-18-IXX-3000</a>
<a class="button blue " href="docs/bwl-t8-18-ixx-3500.pdf" >Model BWL-T8-18-IXX-3500</a>
<a class="button blue " href="docs/bwl-t8-18-ixx-5000.pdf" >Model BWL-T8-18-IXX-5000</a>
<a class="button blue " href="docs/bwl-t8-22-ixx-3000.pdf" >Model BWL-T8-22-IXX-3000</a>
<a class="button blue " href="docs/bwl-t8-22-ixx-3500.pdf" >Model BWL-T8-22-IXX-3500</a>
<a class="button blue " href="docs/bwl-t8-22-ixx-5000.pdf" >Model BWL-T8-22-IXX-5000</a></div>
<br />
<br /></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the closing `</aside>` tag.

Comment: Nailed it! Thank you!!

Comment: @GuyRichards You can always use the [W3C's Validator service](http://validator.w3.org/) to catch this type of error (unclosed tags).

Comment: oops! damn! :D can you delete those comments.. :p

Comment: I actually just tried to use it on another very similar issue I'm experiencing here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ftvz9/

(the items on the right hand side are appearing at the bottom of the screen for some reason) 

Im not sure if I'm missing a tag or not (the tool you mentioned seems to think so - but I cant seem to resolve it by adding the missing tags it mentioned)  Also - Should I post a new question regarding this?